# Show duration between two date+time values in year, month, days, hours, minutes, and seconds in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two date/time fields. I know I can subtract the two to show duration.

But I want to show the duration year, month, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. Something like `1 year, 2 months, 1 day, 23 hours, 5 minutes, 5 seconds`  or `01 02 02 23:05:05`.

I see I can use `DATEDIF` with `Y`, `YM`, and `MD` to get the years, months, and days but I can't figure out how to incorporate hours, minutes, and seconds into that.

And I don't want to use a Google Apps Script.

Comment: Then a custom format should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time calculations can be fiendishly difficult, because there are many edge cases to consider, but you can use `datedif()` and `text()` to do the hard lifting as long as you carry negatives as appropriate.

Put the start moments in column `A2:A`, the end moments in column `B2:B`, and this formula in cell `C2`:

```
=let( 
  durationText_, lambda(start,end,map(start,end,lambda(s,e,let(d_,lambda(u,datedif(s,e,u)),t_,lambda(u,text(e-s,u)),p_,lambda(n,u,switch(n&"","0","","1",n&" "&u,n&" "&u&"s")),r,d_("md")-(timevalue(s)>timevalue(e)),d,if(r<0,day(eomonth(e,-1))-1,r),m,d_("ym")-(r<0),ifs(not(isdate(s)*isdate(e)),iferror(ø),s>e,"ERROR: start is after end",s=e,"0 "&if(timevalue(s),"seconds","days"),true,let(textjoin(", ",true,map({d_("y")-(m<0),mod(m,12),max(0,d),t_("H"),regexextract(t_("H:m"),":(\d+)"),t_("s")},{"year","month","day","hour","minute","second"},p_)))))))), 

  durationText_(A2:A, B2:B)
)
```

The formula uses singular or plural as appropriate, leaves out units whose value is zero, and observes durations where the start time of the day is greater than the end time of the day. When the start moment is `2022-01-01 11:00:00` and the end moment is `2023-01-01 10:00:00`, the formula will correctly get `11 months, 30 days, 23 hours`.

| start | end | duration as text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 0:00:00 | 2023-02-02 1:01:01 | 1 year, 1 month, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, 1 second |
| 2022-01-01 0:00:00 | 2023-06-24 11:12:04 | 1 year, 5 months, 23 days, 11 hours, 12 minutes, 4 seconds |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2022-01-02 10:00:00 | 1 day |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2022-02-01 10:00:00 | 1 month |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00 | 1 year |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2022-02-06 10:15:00 | 1 month, 5 days, 15 minutes |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 2023-01-01 11:15:30 | 1 year, 1 hour, 15 minutes, 30 seconds |
| 2022-01-01 23:59:59 | 2022-01-02 0:00:01 | 2 seconds |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 2022-02-02 10:00:00 | 1 month, 23 hours |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 2022-02-01 10:00:00 | 30 days, 23 hours |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00 | 11 months, 30 days, 23 hours |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 2023-01-02 10:00:00 | 1 year, 23 hours |
| 2023-06-24 0:52:01 | 2023-06-24 0:52:01 | 0 seconds |
| 2023-06-24 | 2023-06-24 | 0 days |
| 2023-06-24 | 2023-06-28 | 4 days |
| 4:44:01 PM | 4:44:03 PM | 2 seconds |
| 4:44:01 PM | 6:59:46 PM | 2 hours, 15 minutes, 45 seconds |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | ERROR: start is after end |

See
[datedif()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612),
[text()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139),
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
and
[map()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985).

For an overview of how date and time calculation works in spreadsheets, see
[Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219)
and
[Working with Dates and Times in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates).

Comment: Hot dog. Wow. This is one complex formula but it works. All the `lambda`'s make it hard to follow. Let me see if I can figure out how it works. Thank you!